# Test firebase cloud messaging with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to test firebase cloud messaging with jest but I have an error with my mock function...

How can I test all function invocations?

`expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()`
`Expected mock function to have been called.`

```
import { Sentry, SentrySeverity } from 'react-native-sentry';
import RNFirebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import Veery from 'react-native-veery';

export default function firebaseCloudMessaging() {
  try {
    const firebase = RNFirebase.app().messaging();

    firebase.getToken().then(Veery.setVeeryToken);

    firebase.getInitialNotification();

    firebase.onMessage(Veery.VeeryNotificationHandler);

    firebase.onTokenRefresh(Veery.setVeeryToken);
  } catch (error) {
    Sentry.captureException(error, { level: SentrySeverity.Error });
    console.warn('Error with firebaseCloudMessaging ', error);
  }
}
```

my test : 
https://gist.github.com/ludwigCDSBDX/82749eb20eac44fffac8d5318864eb6f

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**my mistake:** 
the previous mock creates several instances of mock 
so when I was trying to check if my mock had been called, I was comparing the same function, but not the same function instance !

```
jest.mock('react-native-firebase', () => {
  const app = { messaging: () => messaging };

  const messaging = {
    getToken: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myTokenMock')),
    getInitialNotification: jest.fn(),
    onMessage: jest.fn(),
    onTokenRefresh: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('myMockTokenRefresh')),
  };

return { app: () => app };
});
```